# adding extra information to filename - python

Tags: python

I used the following line to rename my file by adding timing and remove extra space and replace it with (-)
if i would like to add extra information like lable before the timing ,

```
filename = ("%s_%s.mp4" %(pfile, time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S",time.localtime()))).replace(" ", "-")
```

the current output looks like

```
testfile_2016-07-25_12:17:14.mp4
```

im looking to have the file output as

```
testfile_2016-07-25_12:17:14-MediaFile.mp4
```

try the following ,

```
filename = ("%s_%s_%s.mp4" %(pfile, time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S","Mediafile",time.localtime()))).replace(" ", "-")
```

what did i missed here ?

Comment: `filename = ("%s_%s_%s.mp4" %(pfile, time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S",time.localtime()),"Mediafile")).replace(" ", "-")` should work : the string 'MediaFile' was not in the right parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the function strftime incorrectly. Strftime only takes 2 arguments and you're passing it 3.

You would need to generate the string from the time and apply some string operations to append the extra info.

If you want to add MediaFile to the end of the filename simply do something like this.

```
filename = ("%s_%s-MediaFile.mp4" %(pfile, time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S",time.localtime()))).replace(" ", "-")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
filename = ("%s_%s-%s.mp4" %(pfile, time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S",time.localtime()), 'MediaFile')).replace(' ', '-')
# 'testfile_2016-07-25_10:29:28-MediaFile.mp4'
```

To understand better how this works and slightly improve readability, you can define your time stamp in a separate variable:

```
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()) # 2016-07-25_10:31:03

filename = ("%s_%s-%s" %(pfile, timestr, 'MediaFile')).replace(' ', '-')
# 'testfile_2016-07-25_10:31:03-MediaFile.mp4'
```

or

```
filename = ("%s_%s-MediaFile.mp4" %(pfile, timestr)).replace(' ', '-')
```

For completeness, you can also use the `format()` method:

```
filename = '{0}_{1}-MediaFile.mp4'.format(pfile, timestr).replace(' ', '-')
```

Comment: I think he wants to replace the space for '-' in case there are whitespaces in the filename.

Comment: @HolyDanna Fair enough, i'll take it out

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for should be :

```
filename = ("%s_%s_%s.mp4" %(pfile, time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S",time.localtime()),"Mediafile")).replace(" ", "-")
```

In your original code, the 'Mediafile' string was not in the right place : you put it as an argument of strftime(), when you should put it as one of the string to replace, in the 2nd level of parentheses.